# Pass selection Listbox topwindow to main window

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first real Python project. I am currently developing a GUI in Tkinter that allows the user to select Tasks and CVs to automatically compile documents using standard predefined task and CV texts from a database.

I have created two "Add" buttons in the main window to add Tasks and CVs that show a popup Listbox that allow the user to select the Tasks and CVs they want to have included in the commercial proposal. I have managed to create the popup window as a separate Class and it stores the selected Tasks in a list, but now I need to pass the list with the selected items to the Listbox in the main window when the user clicks the Select button in the popup window, but I cannot get my head around on how to do that.

I have researched on different fora and watched a variety of Youtube videos, but all focus on entry popups or some sort.

This is the code for the main window:

```
from tkinter import *
from Add import *

# make main window
root = Tk()

theLabel = Label(root, text="ProposalBuilder")
theLabel.grid(row=0)

# make frames
taskFrame = Frame(root)
taskFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)

CVFrame = Frame(root)
CVFrame.grid(row=1, column=1)

buildFrame = Frame(root)
buildFrame.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

# add labels to frames
taskLabel = Label(taskFrame, text="Tasks")
taskLabel.pack()

CVLabel = Label(CVFrame, text="CVs")
CVLabel.pack()

# add listboxes to frames
scrollTask = Scrollbar(taskFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
listTask = Listbox(taskFrame, selectmode=MULTIPLE, yscrollcommand=scrollTask.set)
scrollTask.config(command=listTask.yview)
scrollTask.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listTask.pack()

scrollCV = Scrollbar(CVFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
listCV = Listbox(CVFrame, selectmode=MULTIPLE, yscrollcommand=scrollCV.set)
scrollCV.config(command=listCV.yview)
scrollCV.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listCV.pack()

# add commands to buttons
def addTask():
    taskBox = Add('C:\\Users\\204703\\ProposalBuilder\\Database')
    sel_test = taskBox.selection

def addCV():
    CVBox = Add('C:\\Users\\204703\\ProposalBuilder\\Database')

# add buttons to frames
buttonAddTask = Button(taskFrame, text="Add", command=addTask)
buttonAddTask.pack(fill=X)
buttonDelTask = Button(taskFrame, text="Delete")
buttonDelTask.pack(fill=X)
buttonUpTask = Button(taskFrame, text="Up")
buttonUpTask.pack(fill=X)
buttonDownTask = Button(taskFrame, text="Down")
buttonDownTask.pack(fill=X)

buttonAddCV = Button(CVFrame, text="Add", command=addCV)
buttonAddCV.pack(fill=X)
buttonDelCV = Button(CVFrame, text="Delete")
buttonDelCV.pack(fill=X)
buttonUpCV = Button(CVFrame, text="Up")
buttonUpCV.pack(fill=X)
buttonDownCV = Button(CVFrame, text="Down")
buttonDownCV.pack(fill=X)

buttonBuild = Button(buildFrame, text="Build Proposal")
buttonBuild.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the code for the separate class I created for the popup window:

```
from tkinter import*
from os import *

class Add:
    def __init__(self, path):
        # the slected tasks
        self.selection = []
        # make a frame
        top = Toplevel()

        # get file names from the directory (path) and save in list
        self.path = path
        self.dirList = listdir(self.path)

        # add listbox to frames and populate with file names
        self.scrollList = Scrollbar(top, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.listbox = Listbox(top, selectmode=MULTIPLE, yscrollcommand=self.scrollList.set)
        self.scrollList.config(command=self.listbox.yview)
        self.scrollList.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        for item in self.dirList:
            self.listbox.insert(END,item)
        self.listbox.pack()

        # add buttons to frame
        self.selectButton = Button(top, text="Select", command=self.select)
        self.selectButton.pack()

        self.quitButton = Button(top, text="Quit", command=top.destroy)
        self.quitButton.pack()

    # identify selected rows and return a list with the selection
    def select(self):
        selectedRows = self.listbox.curselection()
        for item in selectedRows:
                self.selection.append(self.dirList[item])
        print(self.selection)
        return self.selection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: pass the list with the selected items to the Listbox in the main window

You need a reference of the main window Listbox.

I show, how to using `listTask`

1. Extend your `__init__` to accept the reference `target_listbox`

   ```
   class Add:
       def __init__(self, target_listbox, path):
           self.target_listbox = target_listbox
   ```
2. Insert the selected items into `.target_listbox`
   **Note**: Your, `return self.selection` is useless, a `Button.command` **can't process returns**.

   ```
   def select(self):
       selectedRows = self.listbox.curselection()
       for item in selectedRows:
           self.target_listbox.insert(tk.END, self.dirList[item])
   ```
3. Pass the reference `listTask` to `Add(...`

   ```
   taskBox = Add(listTask, ...)
   ```